# Are the M and the V from MVC even needed in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API application that uses one controller which returns data read from a file.

So all I'm using is the C (Controller) part of MVC. I have no Views, and I'm not using Models, either - I'm storing and retrieving the data to/from the App_Data folder.

I know this is a rather simple solution, but it seems that all I need is C, not MVC. Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, but the solution structure does contain Controller, Model, and View folders - and I am using routing and Controller classes to respond to the URLs.

Comment: Your API was recently created? Check my comment at CodeCaster's answer, you may find why this happened to you.

Comment: @jpgrassi: Yes, it was created a day or two ago, in VS 2013.

Comment: So that's what happened. You probably selected the Web Api template and it included all the MVC stuff. If it really bothers you, start again but this time select The Empty template, then mark the option for Web Api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Model-View-Controller is a design pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/tags/model-view-controller.html), to help structure applications that have a GUI. ASP.NET MVC is a framework that helps you build a web application according to this design pattern.

Web API has nothing to do with the MVC design pattern. It was developed separately, temporarily distributed under the same umbrella name and now an own framework altogether: http://www.asp.net/web-api

The fact that some project templates still create "Model" and "Views" directories in your project, means that you're using an outdated project template or one that's assuming you want MVC and Web API in one project.

Comment: This is true. In VS2013, when you start a new Web Application template, if you click on the Web API item, it automatically ticks the checkbox for MVC, thus creating all the structure the OP said. But if you start a new project and select "Empty", them select the checkbox for API. It will only create the Controllers and Models (which most of the time you will need).

Answer (score 3):

CodeCaster's answer already explained very well the "theory" behind your question. Although, I'll contribute with an answer because I stumbled into this months ago and it took some time to figure out why a recently created Web API project also had the Views and all the other items that a ASP.NET MVC application has.

The thing is in Visual Studio 2013, there's the Web Application template. When you select this option, a window is opened. In this window, there is an option for creating a Web Api. The problem relies here. When you select the Web Api in the window (Which of course it's what you want), for some reason it also mark the option for **MVC** in **"Add folders and core references for"** and worse, the checkboxe's are disabled so you can't "uncheck" it (so weird): This is what it looks like:

[image]

If you hit Ok at this time, the API is created with all the MVC references. Probably not what you want.

So, to create a "pure" Web API, that only has references for Web API related files and structure, this is what you need to do:

Select the **Empty** template and then mark the option for **Web API**. :

[image]

Comment: Thanks; the effluvia doesn't really bother me, but next time I'll follow this regimen.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that your controller has actions that will be invoked from a front-end application. The data being sent as the result of that call can be thought of as the model. The front-end app may then use that model to display a view. But you might also.do nothing of the sort. It is up to you as a developer to properly use the MVC pattern if that is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all software patterns start to make most sense as a project increases in size/complexity, and where the scenario in question mirrors the assumptions underlying the pattern. There are a number of trivial scenarios where the Model and View components are either implicit, provided by the framework itself or simply unnecessary. What the MS ASP.NET MVC does in essence is provide a framework that implements the basic MVC pattern within the MS web ecosystem. Whether you need to use the individual features (like EF modelling, Razor views) is up to you.

From your question, your requirements essentially are to allow access to a stored procedure and perform basic data transformation (via the POST) and then to return that data as JSON (via the GET). What is the necessity of the separate GET/POST requests? From your question, the GET relies on a preceding POST request. I would suggest that creating the intermediate JSON file may be unnecessary, rather just look up the data and pipe it back.

Comment: The reason they are two separate operations is that they take place at different times. The POST is called from a utility used to generate the spreadsheet files and send the emails with the attached. The Stored Procedures take several minutes to run, and so returning the results immediately is not possible. By the time the user receives the email, the json file has been created and stored. They then click a link in the email to get back the data as html in a page in their browser. So the POST is (unbeknownst to them, programmatically) called by a utility used by a colleague; the...

Comment: (continued)...GET is called by a user when they click the link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Should we not consider the data returned by the controller action as a view, A view of your data rather than a HTML view, the design pattern does not specify the type of the view. In my opinion its still MVC, the model still exists and you normally would create model of your data that you want to return, the view part is just an other model or view of your core model classes.